# How to deploy a smart contract with the help of Api on bsctestnet

Tags: solidity, dapps, defi

I have created one smart contract and want to create a button on the frontend which will deploy the contract to the testnet whenever we click on it, So is this can be done through an API, and if yes then how can we do that??

Comment: You should google before asking here. 
Everything is available.
https://docs.bnbchain.org/docs/hardhat-new/

Answer (score 0):

I want to use rest api in foundry or hardhat to deploy my smart contract on testnet. Is this something possible?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).